# Unable to create a new electronic signature in Preview

Tags: preview, signature

I am trying to add a signature to the *Preview* using  ***Tools > Annotate > Signature > Manage Signatures***

[image]

I then click on *Create Signature*

[image]

Note that I need to use a camera-ready *picture* of a handwritten signature - (not mouse created).  So in the dialog I choose "Camera", then put the page with signature in front of the camera and click *Done*

[image]

But then the "new" signature is not created: the same single entry is still there (which I did years ago in a much older version of *macOS*).

[image]

Why is a new signature not being created?  I am on *Big Sur*.

**Update** Here is what is in my *Keychain Access*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not make use of the "Trackpad" or "iPhone" options - but only the *Camera* one:

[image]

However on a hunch based on commentary by @grg about possible corruption and @SolarMike about trying other signature methods I went ahead and added a *Trackpad* based signature anyways.  That was successful. I then promptly deleted it - since successful or not that form of signature is of no use to me.

But an apparent side effect is that the *Camera* based signature subsequently succeeded!

Maybe getting the *Trackpad* in there (even if immediately deleting) fixed some kind of corruption or confusion in the storage of the signatures.

Comment: Then perhaps you could consider that since I did the trackpad method FIRST and subsequently tested the others as I pointed out in my comments on my answer it shows I had made it work before you finally got around to it.

Comment: I added that @SolarMike

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the storage of signatures is corrupted.

Try quitting Preview and deleting the ‘Signature Annotation Privacy’ entries in Keychain Access if you don't mind losing the one you already have.

[image]

Previously, the signatures were stored in Preview's container. You can try printing or deleting the store using `read` or `delete` in

```
defaults read ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.signatures
```

Comment: You had briefly shown a command line approach - that actually seemed promising.   I'll also look at this Privacy procedure

Comment: Sorry for the ninja edit. The command line approach was outdated, after I saw it list 2 but I actually have 3 set up in Preview, so then discovered 3 entries in Keychain Access. Preview used to store the signatures in its container, but now uses AnnotationKit and stores them securely in the Keychain.

Comment: interesting sleuthing. i'm working through your Keychain approach now

Comment: Where in the _Keychain Access_ ?  Under "Local items" I do not see _Signature Annotation Privacy" entries; am I looking in the correct place?  Type that I see: "application password", "internet password", "Web form password".

Comment: @West Mine are in the iCloud keychain; the search should find across any keychain. Perhaps that's an issue though, if you've got one signature set up and it's not in this list, it's like they haven't been migrated properly from the container store to the keychain. I haven't added a signature in many years but they show up in Keychain all with the same ‘date modified’. I've put back the information about Preview's signature store plist.

Comment: I do not have iCloud in the left panel .  I just added a  screenshot to the question to show.

Comment: On the assumption that I am not having these signatures synced properly via _iCloud_  I went to _iCloud_ on the mac . But I did not see any settings that applied to _Keychain Access_

Answer (score 1):

So, on Big Sur 11.6 and Preview 11.0

If you click on the sign button then you get the X to delete the signature which you can then replace.

Now it seems to let me create several having created and replaced one…

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I already deleted about six entries and had retried adding a new one- no dice.  How did you go about it?  I put the signature up to the macbook camera, pressed "Done" and then .. nothing .. the new signature did not show up in the list.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects I wrote those examples on the trackpad - there are 3 options for entering…

Comment: OK but I need to do it from a camera.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects as I mentioned, there are 3 methods for entry.

Comment: I saw that: the non camera methods are not meeting my requirements: I use Preview to sign official and financial documents that need a camera-ready version of my written signature.  I have just updated the question to this effect.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects So, for the third time, there are 3 methods: trackpad, Camera and iPhone. Listed in that order and they all work as I have just added extra to the list shown in my answer AND deleted them as I don't actually need them.

Comment: And for the third time I'll mention I already "got" your point but you're not "getting" that a trackpad-scribbled signature does not meet my needs (and the camera version was not working).  You're on the wrong track : the camera works for you and it was not so for me: a useful answer delves into why it's not working and not about trying a different type of signature